# SUM in repository and Paginator

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm looking for a solution to catch SUM of totalHT of my orders linked width campaign :

M yentity :

```
/**
 * Organisation
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WH\CrmBundle\Entity\Order", mappedBy="Campaign")
 */
protected $orders;
```

My Repository :

```
    $qb
        ->createQueryBuilder('Campaign')
        ->leftjoin('Campaign.CampaignType', 'CampaignType')
        ->leftjoin('Campaign.Provider', 'Provider')
        ->leftjoin('Campaign.orders', 'Order')
        ->select('Campaign')
        ->addSelect('Provider')
        ->addSelect('CampaignType')
        ->addSelect('SUM(Orders.totalHT as ca')
    ;

    $qb->getQuery();

    $qb
        ->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $nbPerPage)
        ->setMaxResults($nbPerPage)
    ;

    return new Paginator($qb, true);
```

And My error :

Key "id" for array with keys "0, ca" does not exist in WHCrmBundle:Campaigns:admin/index.html.twig at line 138

I understand i have to create an action in my entity, but i can't creation "get0", so how can i do this sum in a existent field ? Virtual field ? Or a new param in repository ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Look here - it should help: https://anil.io/post/41/symfony-2-and-doctrine-pagination-with-twig